# Redirect to url using squid and squidGaurd

Tags: redirect, squid

Trying to redirect a url to other using squidGaurd, its not working, can anybody help me. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Usecase: the squid is to redirect to http://localhost:3000 for www.abc.com
and works normal for all other urls. Tried many things on internet, not working for me. can Somebody help with some good tutorial or example?

Answer (score 0):

Tarun,

The squidGuard redirection URL should be a valid IP address or FQDN accessible to the clients. In your case traffic may be correctly be correctly redirected to URL http://localhost:3000, but for the clients localhost points to its loopback IP address.

In this case suppose you have opened the URL www.abc.com on your machine, after the request hits Proxy Server your browser is redirected to **http://localhost:3000** so effectively to port 3000 on your machine. Since your machine is not listening on port 3000 it will look like the URL redirection is not working. Please use the IP address or FQDN of the proxy host in place of localhost and it should work.

Shahnawaz